# how to bind data to formGroup in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a dropdown list from which I am selecting a dropdown value.After selecting value it's changing its property according to its type.I want to bind this dynamic form field to formGroup using angular 2

Answer (score 0):

```
 <md-select placeholder="Office" formControlName="office">
            <md-option *ngFor="let option of officeOptions" [value]="option">
              {{ option.name }}
            </md-option>
          </md-select>


  this.form = new FormGroup({
    office: new FormControl()
   });
```

So Now it I will try to fetch a selected value of select box, it will give you updated value.

```
this.form.controls.office.value
```